# VFL in ios autolayout, how to fully fill super view

Tags: ios, autolayout

I am now learning VFL of autolayout. I add a view (`aview`) into a superview (`bview`) by doing

```
bview.addSubView(aview)
```

I want my `aview` to fill the whole `bview`, so my code is:

```
    bview.addSubview(aview);
    aview.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    bview.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    var lays = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("|-0-[aview]-0-|", options:NSLayoutFormatOptions.allZeros , metrics: nil, views: ["aview":aview] as NSDictionary)
    bview.addConstraints(lays);
    lays = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-0-[aview]-0-|", options:NSLayoutFormatOptions.allZeros , metrics: nil, views: ["aview":aview] as NSDictionary)
```

but this code does not run correctly. Am I missing anything?

Comment: What does "not run correctly" mean? What result does this code give you? Does bview have constraints to its superview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to have `-0-`.  Just simply have nothing.  Ex:

```
bview.addSubview(aview);
aview.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
var lays = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("|[aview]|", options:NSLayoutFormatOptions.allZeros , metrics: nil, views: ["aview":aview] as NSDictionary)
bview.addConstraints(lays);
lays = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[aview]|", options:NSLayoutFormatOptions.allZeros , metrics: nil, views: ["aview":aview] as NSDictionary)
```

Comment: You do not need to specify H:, that's the default (it doesn't hurt, but it's not necessary).

Comment: Both of your answer and my code are correct, I make some error in other parts of my code ~ Thx any way...